# Domain host records for github and namecheap

Tags: web-hosting

I have a custom domain with namecheap that I want to redirect to my github page which is at myuser.github.io.

My host records at namecheap have '@' and 'www' A records with an IP of 192.30.252.153. At the root of my github page (in the repo) I have a cname record with mydomain.com. in the file. When I browse to my custom domain in a web browser I get a message that the github page cannot be found.

Ideas? I found a few blog posts about setup, but none of the options worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To support the improved Github Pages, set your records up like this:

```
HOST NAME   IP ADDRESS              RECORD TYPE     TTL
@           192.30.252.153          A (Address)     1800
www         <username>.github.io    CNAME (Alias)   1800
```

Then, fill out one row under SUB-DOMAIN SETTINGS:

```
HOST NAME   IP ADDRESS              RECORD TYPE     TTL
@           192.30.252.154          A (Address)     1800
```

More information here: http://davidensinger.com/2013/03/setting-the-dns-for-github-pages-on-namecheap/

Comment: Thanks this works great! My solution only worked for the root domain, but not with 'www' in front.

Comment: When I hit save, the SUB-DOMAIN settings disappear. Is that normal? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

Namecheap has changed things.  This is what I did:
[image: My Namecheap Configuration]

This is what is working for me.

In my pages repository, the CNAME is just:

```
phillipamann.com
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: The OP is dated and had a working solution. This is more of administrative information for a vendor, not something appropriate as a SO answer.

Comment: The vendor has changed so the information was outdated.  I figured updating the entry could be valuable to future people who Google this question and end up at this question.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was the following...

Hostname  IP  Record Type  TTL

@  204.232.175.78 A(Address) 1800

www  204.232.175.78 A(Address) 1800

Comment: These are not valid IP addresses anymore.